# Approximating an integral representation of the Number Partition Problem

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration, numerical-methods

One can write out an integral whose solution gives the number of solutions to the NP-Complete Number Partition Problem and I'm wondering if anyone has an suggestions or ideas on who to solve or approximate this integral analytically or numerically.

Given $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n-1} \in \mathbb{Z}$, the Number Partition Problem asks for a partition of the $a_k$'s such that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sigma_k a_k = 0$, where $\sigma_k \in  \{  -1,1 \} $.

Consider the following Integral:

$$ I(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (e^{ i a_k \theta } + e^{ -i a_k \theta } ) d\theta $$

$I(\dots)$ will count the number of solutions for a given instance of $(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_{n-1})$.  Solving this integral is worse than NP-Hard (it's #P) so asking for a general solution is out of the question.  But can one do any sort of approximation, either analytically or numerically?  If you choose the $a_k$'s with some distribution, say uniform on some interval, can you exploit that randomness to help you approximate this integral?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

note:  This has been studied by Borgs et all for the [NPP Phase Transition](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.89.9577&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and that's where I first saw this integral representation of the Number Partition Problem, but their analysis relies on approximating the family of instances given a uniform distribution on the $a_k$'s rather than trying to solve a particular instance, as I'm trying to do above.

Comment: I do not see the point of crossposting a question like this.  Answers improve one another if everyone can see everyone else's answers; insights from different answers can be combined.  Splitting up the answers like this seems counterproductive to me.

Comment: There was one answer from the mathoverflow site, otherwise it is essentially unanswered.  Should I add a comment on what has been suggested already?

Comment: Depending on how big the $a_k$ are and how many terms that product has, the integrand can be violently oscillatory, and quite a lot of the usual numerical methods will have trouble with this. Turning this into a contour integral might make it slightly more tractable, though.

Comment: @J.M.,  [Mertens](http://www-e.uni-magdeburg.de/mertens/publications/npp1.pdf) and later Borgs, Chayes and Pittel considered used the method of stationary phase to approximate the above integral when $a_k$'s are replace with the random variable $X_k$, but I do not see how to exploit this to solve the above integral.

Comment: Presumably if $\theta$ goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, you don't need the additional $2\pi$ in the exponents.

Comment: As J. M. says, the size of the $a_k$ is important here. What can you say about them? If they, or many of them, are big (say > 10), you may be able to use asymptotic methods, maybe combined with quadrature. PS: Do you mean $\sigma_k \in \{-1,+1\}$ in the second paragraph?

Comment: @Jitse, I was imagining $a_k$ to be extremely large, typically on the size of $2^n$.  And $\sigma_k$ now reads correctly, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using a discrete Fourier transformation seems more appropriate if the $a_i$ are integers.  The number of solutions is the value of the convolution product
$$
\left(\delta_{a_0} + \delta_{-a_0}\right) * \left(\delta_{a_1} + \delta_{-a_1}\right) * ... * \left(\delta_{a_{n-1}} + \delta_{-a_{n-1}}\right)
$$
evaluated at 0.  This has the obvious dynamic programming solution, which takes something like $O(n A)$ time, where $A = \sum_i |a_i|$; i.e., it is a quasi-polynomial-time algorithm.  If the $a_i$ are chosen at random from (bounded) distributions of integers instead, then the dynamic programming solution takes $O(n A^2)$ to calculate the expected number of solutions.  The discrete Fourier transform translates that problem to a direct product of $n$ functions over $O(A)$ points, each of which can be computed in $O(A \log A)$ using the FFT, reducing the total time to $O(nA \log A)$.  Moreover, the number of "approximate" partitions, i.e., choices of the $\sigma_i$ such that $|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sigma_i a_i| \le k$ for some small $k$, falls out of this calculation essentially for free.

Comment: This is very much like the argument made by Mertens (see [here](http://www-e.uni-magdeburg.de/mertens/publications/npp1.ps.gz)).  The difference in the analysis I presented and considering them as delta functions are very similar.  I should have mentioned that the numbers under consideration are extremely large ($A = 2^m$, where $m$ is within polynomial factor of $n$) and so the order of the dynamic programming solutions becomes exponential.  I was asking for efficient (approximate) algorithms when the elements are drawn from this (uniform) exponential distribution.